# Why my Database Table is not updated when I change Values in DataGridView?

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I put a *DataGridView* named `DataGridView2` on my form.
And I assigned `dataSource` property to a table in my *DataSet*, called "Account".
I set the default setting for dataGridView which allows user to modify it. And I put a *Save* button for user to save changed values from the grid to the database. However it doesn't work.

The code which I use in save button is :

```
Me.Validate()
Me.DataGridView2.Update()
Me.MyDBTableDataset.AcceptChanges()
```

when I debug it in the second line the there is proper value in :

```
DataGridView2.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value
```

which is user modified value in the grid. But when it executes `AcceptChanges` and finishes, no changes applied to my database.

Would be great if somebody can help.
Thanks

Comment: Have you setup data adapter to execute update query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AcceptChanges` does not do what you think it does.  It doesn't save anything.  It actually resets the `DataSet` so that it contains no changes to save.  You can also get rid of that call to the grid's `Update` method as it is useless.  All it does is redraw the grid onscreen.

What you actually need to do is to call `Update` on the same data adapter or table adapter that you originally called `Fill` on to retrieve the data in the first place.  The `Fill` method executes the `SelectCommand` to retrieve data and the `Update` method executes the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` as needed to save changes back to the database.

That `Update` method will implicitly call `AcceptChanges` to indicate that the changes have been saved.  It's rare that you should ever need to call `AcceptChanges` explicitly.

Comment: .Can you please give a small working example. It would help a lot those seeking to work with these objects.

Comment: @webzy, here's one I prepared earlier: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&highlight=